# Lack of use of variables.instance scope using ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: hibernate, oop, orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to bone up my admittedly spotting knowledge in ColdFusion OOP by going though Matt Gifford's book, "Object-Oriented Programming in ColdFusion."  I'm a little behind in my ColdFusion knowledge; I'm well versed in CFML as it applies to ColdFusion 8 but haven't messed much with the new features in 9 and 10 (They're on my To-Do, but I expect them to take time and I want an answer to this point now).  My company recently updated their servers to 10 and we intend on leveraging the new features and functionality.

My question is based off of something that was glossed over in the book and is leading me to confusing and conflicting answers when I throw searches at Google.  My understanding of ORM development in CF8 (using an ORM framework like Transfer, as well as book examples and other readings) places attributes for your bean in the variables.instance scope to insulate the object attributes from application attributes that are meant to exist in the variables scope.  But using the baked-in ORM in CF9 does not use the instance scope; it instead places the object and application attributes together in the variables scope.  For me, this throws of my methodology of development, since I tend to create a function in a lot of my objects that returns all object attributes at once (handy for the initialization of the object, display all of the attributes for the object, and creating a new record from an empty instance instead of manually calling all of my setters or getters individually).

I need an explanation as to why this was done in this manner; to me it doesn't make sense.  Are there other functions that exist within the baked-in ORM that replicate my all-attributes functionality that I'm missing or haven't run into yet?  I've read that there are potential conflicts between this attribute naming process and other variables you may create in functions that aren't stemmed off by var scoping; I don't know if that stuff was resolved in 10 or if it's just nonsense.  Any clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so-call "Instance" scope is just something made up by the CF community and it was not adopted by Adobe and therefore it's not in the Adobe's implementation of ORM.  It has its pros and cons which I won't explain in this answer, but like you, I liked it as well.

To implement the memento pattern without "instance" scope, you need to either write your own `getMemento()` function that returns a struct of all the properties:

```
function getMemento()
{
  var instance = {};

  instance.propertyA = variables.propertyA;
  instance.propertyB = variabels.propertyB;

  return instance;    // note: safer to return a Duplicate() of instance
}
```

or write a generic one using `GetMetaData()`, see:

- http://objectivebias.com/entry/memento-pattern-with-coldfusion-9-s-automatic-getters-and-setters
- http://henrylearnstorock.blogspot.ca/2010/01/cf9-getmemento-that-works-with.html

Comment: Hm.  I wasn't aware this memento name was a reference to a development pattern.  I'll have to work with that and look into it a little more for insight.  Thank you for the reference links.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to this: "I need an explanation as to why this was done in this manner".  OK, that's a reasonable thing to wonder, and I think CF could be more flexible if it made this configurable for the very reasons you cite.

But if you got your answer to I need an explanation as to why this was done in this manner", what are you going to do from there?  Knowing that information is not going to be particularly useful to you.

The answer is - as far as I can tell - "The Adobe CF team didn't think it through as much as they could have, and now we are where we are".  There.  Blunt, but true.  One has to remember that the CF team aren't actually CF developers (they're Java developers), so they're not that au fait with using CF, so they'll've not have encountered the issues that the bulk of CF developers have which would lead them to think "actually, sticking these straight in the variables scope is not a great idea".  I don't blame the individual developers for this (it's better to have a good Java developer than a bunch of CF experts who also know Java), but I do blame Adobe for not having an expert CF developer on the CF dev team too, to sanity check this stuff.  Adobe do engage a bunch of community members to test stuff, but this sort of thing is not necessarily what they're looking for when they're testing (disclosure: I'm one of them).

I think an action point here is to raise a ticket with Adobe to get this dealt with in CF11.  If you raise it, I'll vote for it (because I've had exactly the same experience as you with this).  The bugbase is [here](https://bugbase.adobe.com/).

What you can do in the mean time?  Well you don't have to use the generated accessors CF creates for you, you could roll your own, and stick the property values wherever you like.  You could save yourself for having to write individual accessors for each property by leveraging onMissingMethod(), and looking for method calls to getPROPERTYNAME() and setPROPERTYNAME() and pass those to a generic getter/setter.  Or something like that.